# How to track recursion in javascript without sending a counter variable as argument?

Tags: javascript, recursion, count

I am solving the below problem.

> A row of your plants is infested with bugs! Each day, plants with more
> infestation than the plant to their left will die. Write a function to
> find out how many days it will take for the infestation to end.
>
> For example: If infestation levels for each plant in the row are [3,
> 7, 2, 9, 1, 6, 4] then, on the first day, plants infested at levels 7,
> 9, and 6 will die leaving [3, 2, 1, 4]. On the second day 4 will die
> leaving [3, 2, 1] with no more plants that will die. The answer is 2
> days.
>
> Complete the function plantsDying below. It must return the number of
> days until plants will no longer die from infestation. If a plant has
> a higher infestation number than the plant to it's left, it dies.
>
> @param {array} infestedPlants - Array of the infestation levels of
> the row of plants  @return {number} - Number representing the number
> of days until plants no longer die

Below is the given function to write my code. It can't be edited for taking more arguments.

```
> function plantsDying(infestedPlants) {   /* Enter your solution here!
> */ }
```

I have solved the process of eliminating the infested plants using recursion. However I am not able to keep track of the number of times the recursion happens. Which is the number of days for infestation to end. I can't change the number of arguments that the given function above can take, to accommodate a counter variable.

So, what I did was that I created another function within the given function and passed a counter variable to track whenever a function call is made. I am able to get the right number from that counter variable. However, the website says the answer is not right.

Here is my code below. I am not sure why it is not accepting my answer.

```
function plantsDying(infestedPlants) {
  /* Enter your solution here! */

function recurseee(infestedPlants,count){
     var stack = []
count++
     
for(i=0;i<infestedPlants.length;i++){
    if(infestedPlants[i+1]){
        if(infestedPlants[i+1]>infestedPlants[i])
        {
          stack.push(infestedPlants[i])
          i++
        }
        else{
            stack.push(infestedPlants[i])
        }
    }
    else{
        stack.push(infestedPlants[i])
    }

}

if(stack.length == infestedPlants.length)
count =1
else
count++

console.log(stack)

if(stack.length>0){
    for(i=0;i<stack.length;i++){
        if(stack[i+1])
        {
            if(stack[i]<stack[i+1])
            {
                   count++
             stack = recurseee(stack, count) 
           
            }
        }
        }
    }

  return(count)
  
}

var count = 0

var res = recurseee( infestedPlants,count  )


return res
}

var daysPassed = plantsDying([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

console.log(daysPassed)
```

For this input [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], the corresponding remaining plants after elimination in each recursion call is [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ]
[ 1, 5 ]
[ 1 ]
and the count or the number of days passed is 3.

My code returns the same but the answer doesn't get accepted. I am not sure whether this is because I have used another function within or because the count is possibly wrong. This is my understanding from the explanation in the question.

Please help me understand what is going wrong here and get the correct output. Also please let me know if it is possible to return a count of recursion without using a counter variable.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem but your example below the code seems wrong to me - to me it looks like in the first generation all plants will die except the 7, which of course subsequently remains, so the answer should be 1. In which case, if your function is returning 3, something is wrong with the logic. (Which I haven't studied.)

Comment: FYI: return is not a method call.

Comment: Your recursion returns an array and somehow you have it returning a number? Seems odd

Comment: You are incorrect about what happens with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. On the first day, all plants except the leftmost are greater than the plant to their left, so all these plants die, leaving us only with `[1]`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond & MarkSaving - I had the doubt too initially, but the website still mentioned the answers didn't match when I eliminated all others in one go. Hence I assumed that I have to take them in pairs, from left to right without repetition.

Comment: @epascarello - the variable res will hold the last returned value, in this case the count. That's why it holds the count number and not the new array

Comment: @MarkSaving using the logic you mentioned, other test cases with similar ascending values are also not passing successfully. I thought I will mention this too as I did not earlier...I am relatively new to challenges like this and so I tried all things I could and came here...Please help me with the right understanding, thank you.

Comment: @MarkSaving for the example test case `[3, 7, 2, 9, 1, 6, 4]` , it is also possible to compare the plants while in one loop and eliminate the larger numbers to the right, i.e 7,9,6,4. It will mean that on day one itself all of them were eliminated and the comparison happened sequentially for x in the loop. Guess they call this some sort? Any test case can be handled like that as they are just an array of numbers. When that did not give the successful output, I assumed they are going two at a time, without repetition, from left to right. I am not sure. It confuses me when I think more about it.

Comment: @srinatsrinat No, you can't remove 4 on the first loop because its neighbour to the left is 6. One must wait until after 6 is removed to remove 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common technique when you want the recursion to include variables not in the signature of your main function is to have a separate recursive function that does include them and have the main function simply call that one, supplying the initial values for them.

In the days before writing modules was easy, this would have been done with an internal function, something like this:

```js
const plantsDying = (infested) => {
  const recur = (infested, count) => {
    const afterRemoval = infested .filter ((x, i, a) => i == 0 || a [i - 1] >= x)
    return afterRemoval .length == infested .length 
      ? count 
      : recur (afterRemoval, count + 1)
  }
  return recur (infested, 0)
}

console .log (plantsDying ([3, 7, 2, 9, 1, 6, 4])) //=> 2
console .log (plantsDying ([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))       //=> 0
```

These days its more common to have them as module-private functions, with something like this:

```js
const dying = (infested, count) => {
  const afterRemoval = infested .filter ((x, i, a) => i == 0 || a [i - 1] >= x)
  return afterRemoval .length == infested .length 
    ? count 
    : dying (afterRemoval, count + 1)
}

const plantsDying = (infested) => 
  dying (infested, 0)

// or whatever
// module .exports = {plantsDying, /* ... */}

console .log (plantsDying ([3, 7, 2, 9, 1, 6, 4])) //=> 2
console .log (plantsDying ([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))       //=> 0
```

In either case, notice that this also shows a simpler way to write a single-step removal using `.filter` and its index and array parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for simplifying this. I am able to see where I lost track and went over and over. I also have two new questions. 
1. `(x, i, a) => i == 0 || a [i - 1] >= x` - in this, what does || operator do? 
2. And I tried enclosing this statement within {} and it returns 1 for any input. What is the difference between what you have done and enclosing them in {} ?

Comment: @srinatsrinat: `||` is the [logical `or` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).  It might be a little better with a few extra parentheses: `(x, i, a) => (i == 0) || (a [i - 1] >= x)`.  This will return `true` if `i` is zero or if the prior element (`a [i - 1]`) is greater than the current one (`x`, equivalently `a [i ]`).  When we `filter` with this, we keep only those elements for which this is true.

Comment: @srinatsrinat:  What you tried enclosing within `{` - `}` is not a statement, but an expression, presuming you mean that you wrapped `i == 0 || a [i - 1] >= x` in the braces.  [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) can have a simple expression as their body or can have a `{` - `}` delimited block.  In the latter case, you would have to add a `return` statement:  `(x, i, a) => {return (i == 0) || (a [i - 1] >= x)}`. Or equivalently, `infested .filter (function (x, i, a) {return  (i == 0) || (a [i - 1] >= x)}`)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I understood the use of the operator and also the difference between the statement and expression above. With respect to returning true when i is 0, earlier I understood it as initializing i to 0. And now I wonder why would we want to check if i is 0 at all. Isn't it sufficient compare elements, which will eventually retain the element at i =0 if it is smaller than the element at i = 1?

Comment: @srinatsrinat: Note that the callback to `.filter` is returning a boolean.  We check for `i == 0` first so that we short-circuit and exit in the case `i` is zero, so that we don't try to do `a [-1] > x`.  Of course `a[-1]` doesn't exist, and we don't want to have to think about what happens if we try to compare it to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is something like this:

```js
const remove_dead = (arr) => {
    const new_arr = [arr[0]];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[i - 1]) {
            new_arr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return new_arr;
};

const plants_dying = (plants) => {
    if (plants.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    let count = 0;
    while (true) {
        const new_array = remove_dead(plants);
        if (new_array.length == plants.length) {
            return count;
        } else {
            count++;
            plants = new_array;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works. It needs slight modification as I can't put the remove_dead function outside plants_dying function as the code editor is locked on the website I am solving this problem. Also, I wanted to ask, `while(true)` checks for the presence of plants array or runs till return count is encountered? If there was no return count it will keep running infinitely? In short, which condition is it checking to be true?